# Alterar o nome do desenvolvedor em apps diferentes

Tags: android, google-play

Tenho uma conta de desenvolvedor na GooglePlay. Em todos os apps aparece o mesmo nome de desenvolvedor, gostaria que, para cada um, aparecesse um nome diferente de desenvolvedor.

Comment: Mateus, acho que infelizmente não é possível fazer isso. O nome do desenv. é o nome que você forneceu na criação da conta. Para ter um nome diferente apenas com uma nova conta.

Answer (score 4):

Na verdade, o nome que aparece na loja é do "Publicador". Para o Google, o usuário que criou a conta do Google Play é ao mesmo tempo o Publicador e o Desenvolvedor, mesmo que o real desenvolvedor seja outra pessoa. Cruelmente é como um carro de marca X - para o público, quem "desenvolveu" o carro foi a marca X, não importando os trabalhadores que realizaram o serviço.

Para resolver seu problema, restam então as seguintes soluções:

1. Manter uma só loja e colocar alguma seção de ajuda/sobre nos aplicativos, informando do real desenvolvedor dos mesmos; ou
2. Manter uma só loja e colocar na descrição dos aplicativo na loja informação do desenvolvedor, mas não acho muito comum se fazer isso; ou
3. Manter uma só loja e alterar o nome dos pacotes dos aplicativos, de acordo com o desenvolvedor (com.desenvolvedor1.app_do_desenvolvedor1, com.desenvolvedor2.app_do_desenvolvedor2 etc.), porém com essa solução não se pode verificar facilmente o nome do desenvolvedor e se exigirá uma republicação de todos os aplicativos modificados (contagens de downloads, comentários etc. serão perdidos); ou
4. Criar uma loja nova para cada desenvolvedor e transferir os aplicativos através do seguinte endereço seguindo [o passo-a-passo do Google (texto em inglês)](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6230247?visit_id=1-636324406498455265-3138398880&rd=1), entretanto isto implicará no custo da criação de novas lojas para os desenvolvedores, caso não existam.

Eu particularmente utilizo a primeira solução.

### Edição 1:

Realizando uma pesquisa no Google Play com o texto `pub:XXXX`, pode-se visualizar os aplicativos do Desenvolvedor de nome XXXX, que é o mesmo Publicador ("pub" vem de "Publisher", Publicador). Na URL, aparecerá `https://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:XXXX`.

Entretanto, também é possível realizar a pesquisa com `dev:XXXX` ("dev" de developer, Desenvolvedor). Na URL, aparecerá `https://play.google.com/store/search?q=dev:XXXX`.

Ainda, é possível realizar a pesquisa usando a URL `https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=XXX`, com `XXX` sendo sua conta de usuário Google.

O mais estranho é que realizando a pesquisa com `dev`e com `pub` podemos obter resultados diferentes.

Por exemplo, tenho duas contas de desenvolvedor (chamo-as aqui de A e B). Transferi os aplicativos da conta A para a B após já ter desenvolvido 4 deles. Segue abaixo os resultados das pesquisas:

- `dev:A`: 4 aplicativos
- `dev:B`: 6 aplicativos
- `pub:A`: 3 aplicativos
- `pub:B`: 3 aplicativos

Estarei pesquisando a respeito...